# highest weight module correspondence with irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let g  be a simple Lie algebra. L(λ) be the irreducible g -module of highest weight λ . 
are all highest weight modules irreducible ?

Comment: It is not clear what your second sentence has to do with the question. Of course all $L(\lambda)$ are irreducible. But if $\mu\neq\lambda$ is another dominant weight of $L(\lambda)$, then $L(\lambda)\oplus L(\mu)$ also has highest weight $\lambda$, but it is reducible.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are Verma modules which are highest weight modules and not irreducible.  (Example, $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, Verma module $\Delta(\lambda)$ is indecomposable highest weight, with a simple non-trivial quotient $L(\lambda)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.)  In fact, all highest weight $\mathfrak{g}$-modules form a non-semisimple abelian category (BGG category $\mathcal{O}$).